# Excel auto create next line with data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I want an Excel spreadsheet to automatically extend the range when a user enters data in the next row.

Simple example:

```
  | A   B   C       D
--+-----------------------
1 | 0   1   =A1+B1  =B1+C1
2 | 1   1   =A2+B2  =B2+C2
3 | 1   3   =A3+B3  =B3+C3
4 | 4   3   =A4+B4  =B4+C4
5 |
```

If the user populates `A5` and `B5`, Excel automatically extends the formulas in columns `C` and `D`, setting `C5` to `=A5+B5` and `D5` to `=B5+C5`. Apparently, you need a minimum of four previous lines for this to work.

If I add another column with data validation (e.g. `E`), it doesn't get extended to the next row with all the others.

Is there a way of doing the same trick with data validation? I'd like the validation to extend to the next row as well.

Comment: Use a [table](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664) and set up your formulas and data validation in the table. Both will automatically expand to new rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you describe can be achieved by inserting an Excel Table object. Select your data, then click Insert > Table.

When you create data validation, formats or formulas and apply that to all rows of the table, any new row will automatically include the formats, formulas and data validation.